# Prove that only the last constraint in this LP is tight

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I noticed that, for LP

$$
\begin{aligned}
& \text{min} && t^Tx\\
& \text{s.t.} && Ax \succeq \frac{1}{2}t\\
&&& 0 \preceq x \preceq 1
\end{aligned}
\tag 0
$$

, where

$$t = [1, 2, \cdots, n]^T$$

$$
A = \left(
    \begin{array}{ccccc}
    1                                    \\
      & 1             &   & \huge0   \\
      &       & \cdots                \\
      & \huge1 &   & 1            \\
      &               &   &   & 1
    \end{array}
    \right)
\
$$

, only the last constraint $\mathbf 1^Tx \ge \frac{n}{2}$ is tight. In other words, the LP formulated above is equivalent to the following LP:

$$
\begin{aligned}
& \text{min} && t^Tx\\
& \text{s.t.} && \mathbf 1^Tx \ge \frac{n}{2}\\
&&& 0 \preceq x \preceq 1
\end{aligned}
\tag 1
$$

I noticed this interesting fact by solving $(0)$ and $(1)$ in python with different values of $n$, and notice they give exact same optimal $x^*$.

Naturally I proceed to prove this is the case for any $n$, but I just can't find a way to prove this. I tried writing out the dual problem and tried to prove that only the last dual variable is non-zero, but I can't find a way to express the dual variables.

Comment: Isn't the optimal x just (n/2, 0, 0, 0, ..., 0)?

Comment: @E-A not really. Consider the $n=3$ case, what you suggested means $x_1=3/2$, which is infeasible, since we require $0 \le x_i \le 1$

Comment: Right, didn't see that! Then, isn't the optimal solution both for the original just (1, 1, 1, ..., 1, x, 0, 0, ..., 0) where x is either 1/2 or 1 (depending on if x is even or odd)? You can imagine this as some form of water filling; if you have a solution where the first few buckets aren't filled, you can make things more optimal by shifting your weight to the beginning. (I could still be missing something)

Comment: @E-A Yes! I've figured that out but still appreciate that :)  I was stuck in the dual problem and didn't realize I can obtain the optimal $x^*$ first and then use it to show that only the last constraint is tight. Thanks again!

Comment: All good :D good luck! I will quickly write it up as an answer below in case someone else runs into this specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP seems to have figured out the answer, but here is an answer in case someone else runs into a problem of this sort. The intuition is that you can always shift the values more towards the beginning and get a more optimal solution. Since this same logic applies to both LPs, and they only use the same constraint, they have the same optimal solution.

Now, for this problem, we first need to observe that the optimal solution to the above LP is of the form x' = (1, 1, 1, ..., 1, p, 0, 0, ..., 0) where x is either 1/2 or 1 (depending on if x is even or odd). To see that, suppose you have another optimal solution x* = ($a_1$, $a_2$, ..., $a_n$) which is not the same as the one above. Let $S_i(x) = \sum_{k=1}^i x_k$ (this basically means the sum of the first i coordinates of x).

Since x and x* are not the same, there will be some first i where $S_i (x^*) \not = S_i(x')$. Now, we note that x' maximizes this partial sum for i < n/2; if they are equal for i > n/2, then the solution x* could be made smaller by setting those terms equal to 0. Now, suppose not, i.e. for some i < n/2, since x' maximizes that partial sum, we have $S_i(x*) < S_i(x')$. Now, since x* is a solution, we must have an $x^*_j > x'_j, j > i$ (since all the terms of x* should sum up to at least n/2). However, then, increasing the value in i and decreasing in j makes * more optimal.